# How to restrict user logging in particular application using CAS?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cas

I am working on providing single sign on feature to the applications I have. I am using CAS for this along with spring. I am able to make it working for all the applications. But one doubt I have is, Is it possible to restrict user for any one application for which he is not having access? I mean is there a way to provide application level authorization using CAS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can customize CAS to return a complex object including the role of user só then the each APP be responsible for authorization. Herecwe do this using Spring Security